# Scrapy - How to Retry certain proxies for all requests just once?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this custom scrapy proxy rotation middleware in my spider:

```
packetstream_proxies = [
    settings.get("PS_PROXY_USA"),
    settings.get("PS_PROXY_CA"),
    settings.get("PS_PROXY_IT"),
    settings.get("PS_PROXY_GLOBAL"),
]

unlimited_proxies = [
    settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_1"),
    settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_2"),
    settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_3"),
    settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_4"),
    settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_5"),
    settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_6"),
]


class SdtProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta["proxy"] = random.choice(packetstream_proxies)
        if request.meta.get("retry_times") == 1:
            request.meta["proxy"] = random.choice(unlimited_proxies)
            return None
```

My goal was to retry `packetstream_proxies` just one time for all requests after that it should retry with `unlimited_proxies` but above middleware is not working as expected it is retrying `packetstream_proxies` more than one time as I have set the `RETRY_TIMES = 25`.

How can I customize the proxy retries in order to achieve my expected goal?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you want to do all the requests with `packetstream_proxies` and once you need to do one or many retries choose an `unlimited_proxies`.

So you just need to fix your code in order to avoid errors with `retry_times` because in the first request it won't exist, so you need something like this:

```
class ProxyRotationMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta["proxy"] = random.choice(packetstream_proxies)
        # For avoid have error when retry_times does not exist, just add default 0
        if request.meta.get("retry_times", 0) > 0:
            request.meta["proxy"] = random.choice(unlimited_proxies)
```

Hope I answered your question, because I work a lot with middlewares and proxies in my [job](https://bitmaker.la)

Comment: Hi! I have another question similar to proxy rotation but with different condition can you please take a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75501618/custom-scrapy-proxy-rotation-middleware-with-specific-retry-condition