# Custom scrapy proxy rotation middleware with specific retry condition

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a few conditions to implement for rotating proxies in scrapy middleware:

1. If `response` is not `200` try that `request` with another random proxy from a list.
2. I have two lists of proxies let's say I'd like to start crawling with first list of proxies and retry about 10 times with that list and after that as a last resort I want to try second proxy list.

I have tried creating the middleware but it is not working as expected it is not rotating proxies as well as not picking up the second proxy list as last resort. Here is the code:

```
class SFAProxyMiddleware(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.settings)

    def __init__(self, settings):

        self.packetstream_proxies = [
            settings.get("PS_PROXY_USA"),
            settings.get("PS_PROXY_CA"),
            settings.get("PS_PROXY_IT"),
            settings.get("PS_PROXY_GLOBAL"),
        ]

        self.unlimited_proxies = [
            settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_1"),
            settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_2"),
            settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_3"),
            settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_4"),
            settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_5"),
            settings.get("UNLIMITED_PROXY_6"),
        ]

    def add_proxy(self, request, host):
        request.meta["proxy"] = host

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        retries = request.meta.get("retry_times", 0)
        if "proxy" in request.meta.keys():
            return None
        if retries <= 10:
           self.add_proxy(request, random.choice(self.unlimited_proxies))
        else:
            self.add_proxy(request, random.choice(self.packetstream_proxies))
```

Am I doing something wrong implementing the middleware? Thanks

Comment: do you have the middleware enabled in your settings? And do you have the necessary http codes set in your settings?

Comment: Yes I have enabled the middleware in custom settings `"sdt.middlewares.SFAProxyMiddleware": 350,` and in `settings.py` I have defined the retry http codes `RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504, 520, 400, 403, 406, 408, 429]` as well.

Comment: cool! looking forward to your test results.

Comment: Nevermind... I can't run tests because I don't have access to the proxy lists.

Comment: Can we talk on chat?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252147/newroom